# Visual studio 2008 crashes when starting to debug

Tags: visual-studio, crash, debugging

When I press F5, everything compiles fine, but when the app is to be started, VS crashes, showing the "Just in time debugger" dialog.

More than one (similar) solution has this problem. A new solution containing just a form, works. This problem started out of the blue, I have made no changes to the environment as far as I can understand.

I can start the app without debugging (ctrl+F5), and then attach the debugger.

I'm using VS 2008 sp 1.

Comment: do you have any firewall or application controling system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem now. I had "Step framework source" enabled, which somehow broke the debugger (strange though, because it usually works). Turning that off, made me debug as usual again.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to debug a vsto add-in for Outlook. VS2008 was always crashing, after the build completed, when it was trying to attached the debugger to the add-in. Very frustrating, but then I saw this answer and tried it and my problem was solved!

Comment: Also remember to close other instances for visual studio before you do then then close the instance you changed the setting on so the change is enforced on all new visual studio instances.

Answer (score 9):

Never seen this issue, have you tried turning off all your plug-ins like reSharper, CodeRush, etc.?

---

**Update:** When worst comes to worst I usually try this command line.

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs 
devenv.exe /Setup
```

try all these you can do them all at once or do them individually it is up to you.  But be aware that you will be deleting all your settings that you have customized in to Visual Studio, so you may want to back them up.

The last thing you can try is this, to see if the problem is with something weird that is running.

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

*Starts Visual Studio in safe mode, and loads only the default environment and services, and shipped versions of third-party packages.*

Comment: I have no plug-ins. I use TotalSvn though, but nothing in my environment has changed.

Comment: Very useful suggestions! You may want to add this suggestion by Sheng Jiang 蒋晟 to save a debug log and send to microsoft: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785271/debug-techniques-visual-studio-2008-process-fatal-crash-after-debug-of-wpf-appli/1785455#1785455

Comment: Starting Visual Studio in SafeMode worked for me. I'm still not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have undocked windows in debug layout search KB960075 on code.msdn.microsoft.com (can't add hrefs).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CLI.exe error issues?  Check your event log.  I've had the same issue and simply re-staged my machine out of panic since I was so near a deadline.  I assumed that it was an issue with the registry and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Interesting, not CLI.exe, but a lot of these:

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3082 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A2E1132) (0)

Answer (score 0):

try repair or reinstall, don't waste time findin' the reason of the problem

Comment: this would work as it would reset the "Step framework source" setting to its default (which is off) but would take much longer than doing the marked answer.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion because it takes a lot of time, may not resolve the issue, and won't help you understand why the issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now, after my computer rebooted itself last night. When I was pressing F5 the app started but instantly shut down and the VS IDE crashed. 
To fix it: `Debug->Delete All Breakpoints`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, out of the blue the IDE would crash when I started to debug.  Happened with any existing project that I opened, even the visual studio samples.  I created a new project, just a blank dialog, ran it, and all was good.  After that, the problem went away and I was able to debug again.