# Debug Techniques: Visual Studio 2008 Process fatal crash after debug of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, fatal-error

I have a relatively large C#/WPF Visual Studio 2008 solution that I am trying to test and synchronize across 2 developer's computers. On my computer, I am able to build and debug (run) the project successfully without errors.

On the second computer, I am able to build the solution without any errors. When I attempt to run the solution, Visual Studio starts the process but about 3 seconds later the entire development platform exits. Before it exits I briefly see one of our .xaml files opened by visual studio with a yellow 'unhandled exception' box pop-up on a certain line number. I'm currently contacting the part of my company who is responsible for implementing the functionality of that xaml file.

This raised a bigger issue in my mind: **How can you troubleshoot an issue when Visual Studio is immediately exiting after attempting to run a program?**

[The Visual Studio 2008 crashes when starting to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882052/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-starting-to-debug) post may also be helpful. I'm trying those solutions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that executing the three following commands helped to fix our problem:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs 
devenv.exe /Setup
```

This was suggested in [another stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882052/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-starting-to-debug/882068#882068) helped us to determine that it was a plugin, AccuRev's Visual Studio plugin, that was causing the issue.

The issue also appears to be a "known issue" with a hotfix from Microsoft, [documented here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB960075).

> VS2008 SP1: In Visual Studio 2008 SP1, having windows in non-default locations, for example after docking and undocking windows, when switching between debugging and designing or switching to/from full screen, can result in a crash of the Visual Studio IDE.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Run [devenv/debugexe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274(VS.80).aspx) to debug your exe. When an unhandled exception occurs, in the debug menu, select "[save as dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk551230.aspx)", then visit http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio to open a bug report and attach the dump file after creating the report.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I suggested your debug techniques should be added to the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882052/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-starting-to-debug/882068#882068