# Where is 'step framework source' in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash

I'm trying to figure out a crash, and when I see here:

[Visual studio 2008 crashes when starting to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882052/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-starting-to-debug)

it seems that turning off a setting seems to do it. However, I can't find this setting. Now, I'm not writing .NET code, just C++, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Any ideas?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "step into framework source".  It's under "options" "debugging" "general" see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx for a screenshot and description.